# How to properly read an InputStream with multiple contents

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    // Server sends 3 numbers to the client
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bos.write(1000);
    bos.write(2000);
    bos.write(3000);

    // Client receive the bytes
    final byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();

    ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
    System.out.println(bis.read());
    System.out.println(bis.read());
    System.out.println(bis.read());
}
```

The code above is breaking because `bis.read()` [returns an int in the range 0 to 255](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html#read--)

How can I receive those numbers properly? Should I use a delimiter and keep reading the stream until I find it? If so, what if I'm sending multiple files, I think if the delimiter as a single byte it could matched somewhere in the file and also break.

Comment: Always read the documentation of the APIs you are using. The problem is not only about "receiving those numbers", it's also about writing them. You thought you had written 1000, 2000 and 3000 but in fact you haven't. See https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/io/OutputStream.html#write(int) - "Writes the specified byte to this output stream. The general contract for write is that one byte is written to the output stream. The byte to be written is the eight low-order bits of the argument b. The 24 high-order bits of b are ignored."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use decorators for your streams!

All you have to do is to wrap your Output- and InputStream by `java.io.ObjectOutputStream` / and `java.io.ObjectInputStream`. These classes support writing and reading ints (a 4-byte value) with a single method call to `writeInt`/`readInt`.

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
    os.writeInt(1000);
    os.writeInt(2000);
    os.writeInt(3000);
    os.close();

    // Client receive the bytes
    final byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();

    ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
    System.out.println(is.readInt());
    System.out.println(is.readInt());
    System.out.println(is.readInt());
```

Don't forget to close the streams. Use try/finally or try-with-resources.

Comment: I don't think an `ObjectInputStream` is the best idea, I'd use a `DataInputStream`. It is the correct answer though.

Comment: Both, `DataOutputStream` and `ObjectOutputStream` will work. It does the same thing internally. `DataOutputStream` is for primitive types only, while `ObjectOutputStream` also supports complex classes using the standard serialization framework. See `java.io.Serializable`.

Comment: Yeah, but it's recommended to stay away from Java serialization (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dOgfWXw9VrI, https://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/amber/serialization.html). And since OP only wants to write some `int`s, I'd say it's at least clearer to use `DataInputStream`.

Answer (score 0):

Byte stream is a stream of bytes. So if you're reading stream and want to differentiate between different parts of the stream then you should "create" some sort of protocol.

Here are some ideas that can be relevant:

1. Use delimiter as you've stated by yourself, If you're concerned about the length - do not one byte length, but something more unique - something that you're sure you won't see in the parts themselves.
2. At the beginning of the part allocate N bytes (2-4 or maybe more, depending on data) and write the size of the part that will follow.
   So that when you create the stream (writer), before actually streaming the "part" - calculate its size and encode it. This is a protocol between reader and writer.
   When you read - read the size (=N bytes for example), and then read N bytes. Now you know that the part is ended, and the next part (again, size + content) will follow

Comment: Just to make it explicit - the `int` value `read()` returns is actually one byte of the stream.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try [ByteBuffer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/class-use/ByteBuffer.html) class?

ByteStream is just a stream of bytes. It doesn't understand integer which actually needs more than one byte. If you print `bytes.length` it will return you 3. Surely you need more bytes than that. Allocate 4 bytes before you write an integer and then write to it. Check out this class above. Hope that helps!